# Switch lambdas to arm64 in Serverless framework

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to switch all my lambdas to arm64. I am using the serverless framework and I added the architecture tag as mentioned in docs.

```
provider:
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  name: aws
  architecture: arm64
```

But the problem is it's not updating in the lambdas.

Is it because I need to update the serverless package I am using so that cloud formation?
I could not find anything about it

```
    "serverless": "^1.52.0",
    "serverless-plugin-optimize": "^3.1.1-rc.1",
    "serverless-plugin-split-stacks": "^1.7.0",
    "serverless-plugin-typescript": "^1.1.9",
```

These are the dependencies I am using. Not sure if it's because of my serverless framework version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check for the serverless framework's [releases](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/releases?page=1#repo-content-pjax-container) its listed under 2.61.0. So you need to update the dependency version to get support for it in serverless framework

[image]